# Enterprise Architect Generate Source Code

Tags: configuration, directory, enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architecture to generate C++ classes.
Every time I do a Generate Code, it forces me to navigate to the directory I want to save the files to.  Is there a configuration setting for a project or model to tell it to always generate the files to directory X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'Auto Generate Files' (in the Code generation window) should set the path name to the files automatically, and once a file path is selected, you wouldn't have to select the directory again.

Comment: Ah... I see...It's a little misleading...There's no entry for the "root directory" so I assumed I had to reenter it each time, but it's there even if it doesn't show up.